# write and read a structure into a file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to write the following structure into a file and read it back.  The issue I am having is I do not know how to use the fread and fwrite functions properly!

```
struct M{
    char album[50];
    char artist;
    char category;
    float price;
    int   stock;
};
struct M s[10];
```

I tried some code I found here, but the output from the file has strange characters.  I guess it isn't working properly.

Comment: Voting -1 for lack of research effort. There's umpteen tutorials around on using these functions both for single pieces of data and for using them to serialize structures like this.

Comment: A duplicate question means your problem is similar enough to that problem that the solutions provided are the same.  It has nothing to do with who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want `artist` and `category` to be array of char too.

```
struct M{
    char album[50];
    char artist[50];
    char category[50];
    float price;
    int   stock;
};
struct M s[10];
```

then you can use fwrite this way

```
fwrite(s, sizeof(s), 1, file);
```

or equivalently

```
fwrite(s, sizeof(M), 10, file);
```

You can read in the same manner:

```
fread(s, sizeof(s), 1, file);
```

or equivalently

```
fread(s, sizeof(M), 10, file);
```

but you will need to open the file before

```
FILE * file = fopen("thisFile", "bw"); // binary write mode
```

or

```
FILE * file = fopen("thisFile", "br"); // binary read mode
```

Close the file when you're done.

```
fclose(file);
```

And check that file is not == NULL after fopen.

However, you will soon want to read/write a file with a size unknown at compile time.
So you will want dynamic memory allocation based on the file size.
But that's for another question ;)

All the info you need can be found there: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: @user3121023 Yes. There's also "a" to output at the end of a file.